# RTC counter wrap mode

Tags: embedded, rtc, time, soc, real-time

can any one plz help me out with the following queries

In synopsis datasheet for RTC we have one feature i.e Counter wrap mode enter image description here
[image]

my understanding for this feature -> RTC is 32bit i.e 2^32 = 4295947296 seconds counter will increment until it reaches the top value of 0xFFFFFFFF(i.e 4295947296 valid for 136 years)beyond this wraps to 0x00000000. does my understanding correct ?

Comment: You made a mistake in your hex to decimal conversion. FFFF FFFF  = 2^32 - 1 = 4,294,967,295. In general, the largest unsigned integer that can fit in a register with N bits is 2^N - 1. Not 2^N.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in principle.

The second bullet point indicates that the wrap-around can happen at other values than 0xFFFFFFFF, or to another value than 0x00000000. Unfortunately you did not provide a URL to the specific document. The findings of a web search are behind a paywall.